# Comment post not allowed (400) :Missing content_type or object_pk field

Tags: django

Being new to django & trying some fun i'm stucked, I got error:

```
Comment post not allowed (400): Missing content_type or object_pk field.
```

My form.html file:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <form action="/comments/post/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <p><label>Post a comment:</label><br />
        <textarea name="comment" rows="10"
            cols="60"></textarea></p>
        <input type="hidden" name="options"
            value="{{ options }}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="target" value="{{ target }}"  />
        <input type="hidden" name="gonzo" value="{{ hash }}" />
        <input type="submit" name="post" value="submit comment" />
    </form>
{% else %}
    <p>Please <a href="/login/">log in</a> to post comments.</p>
{% endif %}
```

can someone help?

Comment: Show the Python code where the error is coming from + full traceback would be helpful to identify the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Complementing on @Brandon's answer, you need to supply fields required by django_comments (for security reasons, and to wire the comment to your content).
This snippet, taken from the default `comments/form.html` template, should make it work:

```
<form action="/comments/post/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {% if field.is_hidden %}
            <div>{{ field }}</div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    ... your fields here
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're supplying your own form for the [django-contrib-comments](https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments) app, you need to include several fields, one of which is the object id for the object you're commenting on. Otherwise Django doesn't know how to build the association between the comment and the object.

You need to take a look at: https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments/blob/master/django_comments/forms.py

To see all of the fields on the form that are required, and then add them to your custom template.